# Monitor transactions to an address

Tags: monitoring

In Ethereum, how can I get a notification when someone make a transaction to my address?

I found there's a way of scanning the blocks by `rpc`. Is there any other way, like using a public API?

I have tried [blockcypher.com](https://www.blockcypher.com/), but its `webhook` is not working when I test.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it does what you want: https://etherscan.io/apis#logs

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help.

curl -X POST 
https://api.etherscan.io/api 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-d '{
"module": "NewTx",
"action": "subscribe",
"apikey": "Your_API_Key",
"event": "NewBlock",
"url": "https://yourserver.com/webhook",
"address": "address_you_want_to_monitor"
}'

Answer (score 0):

You can use subscriptions to monitor incoming transactions. It should be more reliable than any API since it comes directly from the network.

Here is an example using `web3.js`

```js
import { Web3 } from "web3";

const NODE_URL =
    "YOUR_WEBSOCKET_USER";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

const walletAddress = "ADDRESS_TO_MONITOR";

async function subscribeToNewBlocks() {
  try {
    const event = "newBlockHeaders";
    const subscription = await web3.eth.subscribe(event);

    console.log(`Connected to ${event}, Subscription ID: ${subscription.id}`);

    // Attach an event listener to the subscription object for 'data'
    subscription.on("data", handleNewBlock);
    subscription.on("error", handleError);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error subscribing to new blocks: ${error}`);
  }
}

async function handleNewBlock(blockHeader) {
  console.log(`Scanning for transactions to: ${walletAddress}`)
  //console.log("New block header:", blockHeader);
  
  // Fetch the full block data to access transactions
  const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockHeader.number, true);
  
  if (block && block.transactions) {
    block.transactions.forEach((tx) => {
      // Check if the transaction was to MY_ADDRESS
      if (tx.to && tx.to.toLowerCase() === walletAddress.toLowerCase()) {
        console.log("Incoming ETH transfer:", tx.hash);
        console.log(`From: ${tx.from}`);
        console.log(`To: ${walletAddress}`); // To confirm the address monitored
        console.log(`Value: ${web3.utils.fromWei(tx.value, 'ether')} ETH`);
        console.log("--------------------------------");
      }
    });
  }
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error("Error when subscribing to new block headers:", error);
}

subscribeToNewBlocks();
```